# How to make mysql query with three tables

Tags: mysql

I have three tables:

Products:

```
IDproduct    Name        reference      stock       shop
1            reloj       1234           2            1
2            pulsera     5678           3            1
3            anillo      91011          2            2 
4            colgante    121314         1            2
```

Shops

```
IDshop      
1        
2
```

Orders

```
IDorder   Ordersid_shop     id_product     rate
1               1             2           3
2               1             3           5
3               2             4           2
4               1             4           2
5               2             1           4
6               2             5           5
7               1             1           2
8               1             1           3
```

I want to obtain query:

```
IDproduct  Idshop  MediumRate
   1         1       (3+5+2+4+2+3)/6=3.16
   2         1       3.16
   3         2       (2+4+5)/3=3.66 
   4         2       3.66
```

But when i make this query:

```
SELECT iDorder, rate, ROUND((SUM(rate)/SUM(if(rate> '0', 1, 0))),1) as MediumRate, IDshop, IDproduct, shop
FROM Shops 
INNER JOIN Products ON shop= IDshop
INNER JOIN Orders ON Ordersid_shop = IDshop
ORDER by IDproduct
```

I obtain this:

```
IDproduct  Idshop  MediumRate
   1         1       3.1
```

Only one register

Comment: Query is invalid and should fail without GROUP BY..

Comment: Maybe this query that I wrote here is wrong because it is not the original that has many more fields. The original does not fail but only returns a record

Answer (score 2):

This Select statement

```
  Select iDorder, rate, ROUND((SUM(rate)/SUM(if(rate> '0', 1, 0))),1) as MediumRate,     IDshop, IDproduct, shop
  From orders 
  inner join shops  on Ordersid_shop = IDshop
  inner join products on id_product = IDproduct
  Group by IDproduct
  order by IDproduct;
```

gets you

```
 iDorder    rate    MediumRate  IDshop  IDproduct   shop
   5         4        3            2        1         1
   1         3        3            1        2         1
   2         5        5            1        3         2
   3         2        2            2        4         2
```

You have to start with orders and then innerjoin the rest